# How to provide custom Function/Line/File information to manually invoked Crashlytics Crashes

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have a set of custom functions that's basically wrappers to logging and assertion behaviours. In particular there is an assert class function and a fatal class function. Both which generates a log and then proceed to assert() or fatal().

In my particular case, I have Crashlytics installed. So the generated log message will also go to CLSLogv(). The assert()/fatal() then generates a Crashlytics crash report. These all work fine.

My problem is in the Crashlytics dashboard, it basically just gives me my wrapper function/file/line information as my Issue Title and Description. In essence then every single assertion event, despite of differing causes/callers, will look the same on the Crashlytics Dashboard. Invoking Crashlytics.sharedSession().crash() instead of assert()/fatal() does not help either, as crash() does not allow any arguments for function/line/file.

Is there any other ways of doing this? Or is this essentially an enhancement request to Crashlytics/Fabric/Google? Thanks!

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. The below answer is the best way to add this custom information and feature request noted!

Comment: Yeah. I can get the information into the log. But I was hoping that the correct crash function/line/file information will be visible as the titles in the Dashboard to make quick differentiation of problems possible. As it is, we'd have to click into each individual issue to find out the stack, or even the log

Comment: Thanks and understood! There isn't a way to customize how we group those. Depending on what you're trying to assert or check, you could also consider a non-fatal exception approach: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/logged-errors.html But entirely dependent on what you're trying to check as most asserts are intended to fail hard if the assert is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Swift allows you to use these special values: `#file`, `#function`, `#line` and `#column`. Using them with `CLSLogv()` may help you find the exact places your code went through:

```
CLSLogv("I was here: %@.%@, %i:%i", getVaList([ #file, #function, #line, #column ]))
```

Result in Crashlytics dashboard:

```
1 | 2017-09-05T08:32:22.088Z | I was here: /Users/.../SettingsTableViewController.swift.viewDidLoad(), 27:82
```

Hope this helps :).

Comment: I have no problem getting function/line/file into the Log. But the crash title is still just my wrapper. I am talking more about the Crash title so it's much easier to tell different issues apart from a quick glance from the dashboard without diving down into the Log.  
This is what my log currently looks like:  
7 | 04:41:45:715 (UTC) | 5 | 000A5F62 | JournalViewController.swift:260 | displayMoment | Markup not available even tho Moment deemed Loaded  
But the Crashlytics Dashboard is still just littered only with my wrapper information.  
![Screenshot](https://ibb.co/kabfgv)

Comment: @BiscottiGelato I see... I'm not aware of any settings with which you could change the title of the crash appearing in the dashboard...